# React MUI MS Word like add row functionality to Table

Tags: reactjs, html-table, material-ui, react-hook-form, react-typescript

How could I implement an add row functionality for MUI's Table, sg like in MS Word, when you hover over a row and on the side a little plus icon appears and you can insert a row in that position?
I would also have to somehow connect it to react-hook-form's fieldarray.

I was wondering if it's even possible to add such a feature for MUI or it would be wiser to create it from the ground up using native html tags.